# Clear meshes in blender game

Tags: game-engine

I wish to make a hologram in my blender video game, but I don't know how to make objects transparent. I see tutorials everywere for cycles render but for some reason not game, anything helps.

Comment: This BGE book might help you: https://github.com/mikepan/GameEngineBook/blob/master/text/05-Graphics.md